# For Loop in Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop, terminal

I am using this for loop in the linux terminal:

```
for i in {1..21}; do
```

Here the script makes the loop go from 1 to 21.

How would I write the for loop, so that it goes through specific numbers; let's say:

> 9, 24, 29, 32, 38.

I am using Terminal on Linux.

Comment: There is no pattern to it - `9, 24, 29, 32, 38` unless you have one, you can't use brace expansion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a fixed list of numbers, just put them after *in* separates by spaces:

```
for i in 9 24 29 32 38 
do 
  echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 1):

third argument is incremental sequence by default it take 1

```
for i in {0..21..9};
do
 echo "$i"
done
```

but there is no pattern as you need